# WordPress themes issues

Tags: wordpress-theming

As is said when i login in histinger account, click manage website my wordpress dashboard will open and when it opens in the appearance- theme will show the pop up notification that ( Your active theme is not supported by Quick Demo Import. Visit this link to integrate the Quick Demo Import plugin with your theme )

and when i try to open the link i don't understand wt setup to be done because it's all coding i don't understand illiterate wt to do with that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ty1u.png)

Comment: Please, check the below answer. Hopefully solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your current theme is ASTRA & the theme doesn't support Quick Demo Import Plugin. You can uninstall/disable the plugin form plugin section or ignore the message.

Starter Templates — Elementor, WordPress & Beaver Builder Templates is preferred for ASTRA theme. You can choose any demo after installing this plugin. Its a fremium plugin ; you can only import free versions demo easily. I include this plugin link below:

[Starter Templates — Elementor, WordPress & Beaver Builder Templates](https://wordpress.org/plugins/astra-sites/)